# Which bit is the address of an integer?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

It's pretty simple. Let's say I have:

```
char x = -1;
```

Then in memory, I have (most likely?)

```
 11111111
(01234567)
```

So my question is, if I write `&x` is the address I get back the address of bit 0 or bit 7 and is this the most or least significant bit?

What about in the case of a 32bit integer?

Comment: On most architectures, bits aren't addressable, so the address designates the full byte. Re 32-bit integers, that depends on the endianness of the platform.

Comment: Yes, how are you proposing to get the address of a *bit* exactly? The premise is flawed because you cannot.

Comment: Sorry about that. I asked a poor question being rushed. The answers that I got helped me out though. I was looking to know the case of a 32bit integer with 4 bytes, which byte is pointed to by the address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bits are not individually addressable. The smallest addressable unit of memory is the byte. So in the case of a `char`, when you take its address you get a pointer to that byte. Not any particular bit within that byte, the whole byte. The only way to access individual bits within that byte is via bitwise operations like masking and shifting.

For a 32-bit integer you can address the 4 bytes individually. In that case whether its address is the address of the least significant or the most significant byte depends on the architecture's [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). On a big endian system the address will be the address of the most significant byte. On a little endian system it will be the least significant byte.

```
uint32_t n = 0x11223344;
uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *) &n;

if (*p == 0x11) {
    // big endian
}
else if (*p == 0x44) {
    // little endian
}
```

Answer (score 5):

the memory address are byte-addressed, not bit addressed. Which means you will - depending upon the type of architecture(big endian or little endian) you will get the most significant **byte** or least significant **byte** not specific *bit*

Thanks to WhozCraig, yes - since your variable is a `char` it is the address of the `char` or the byte itself.

Comment: +1: Note that in the case of the OP's question (the address of a *char* variable) there is but-one byte (usually), and it is by-default significant =P

Comment: astute observation sir @WhozCraig :-)

Answer (score 2):

In C, the memory is **byte addressable**, also interpretation of char is byte.  A char is consist of one byte and for example int is consist of four bytes so `char x;` then `&x;` is address of char not bit/byte. if youe take `int i`  then `&i` is address of int object. we are refreshing variable/ complete object.

In memory address scheme is like, each bytes are memorized(*address stored*).

```
  0     1   2    3   4   5    6     7    8   9    10   11  12  13   14   15 
+----+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+
| 1  |  2 | 3  | 4 | 5 |  6 |  7 | 8  | 0  |  1 |  1 | 2 | 3 | 4  |  5 | 6  |  
+----+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+---+---+----+----+----+
             ^                          ^
             |                          |
+----+----+  |                          |
|   add1  |--|                          |
+----+----+                             |
|   add2  |-----------------------------|
+----+----+
```

In this figure `addr1` represents bit 0-7 in case of char and `addr2` represents bit 8-15.
I mean to say ofcouser bit can be numbered(0-15), but *efficient is to access one byte at a time*. and even if you need one bit information its good to read complete byte.

Have you read this question: [*What exactly is a C pointer if not a memory address?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151377/what-exactly-is-a-c-pointer-if-not-a-memory-address). If your asking about C: *A pointer value can be some kind of ID or handle or a combination of several IDs*

> So `&x` is just an **reference** in C. It references one byte for `char` and four byte for `int`

Additionally,

Although memory is byte addressable but fortunately, we *have access at bit level thought [bitwise operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) and [bitwise structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12482806/structures-with-bitwise-data-in-c)*.

Comment: yes, I remember that linked question of "what exactly is a C pointer.. " pretty well. It enlightened me and I am still awestruck at the deep understanding of AlexeyFrunze(a Microsoftie btw). Excellent question as well as the most insightful answer by Alexey there.

Comment: @Aniket Yes, the question was interesting and AlexeyFrunze really gives good answers. BTW which clg you are from? In your profile you have not mentioned.

Comment: I am done with colleges. I studied electrical engineering in BMSCE bangalore. @GrijeshChauhan

Comment: @Aniket but you have done good stuff in computer science. an better than me I am from CS and from [MNIT](http://www.mnit.ac.in/new/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26889/discussion-between-aniket-and-grijesh-chauhan)

Answer (score 1):

Addresses refer to bytes in memory -- bits don't have their own individual addresses.

That said, lets assume that the value is larger than a single byte:

```
long x = -1;
```

In that case, the value takes up 32 bits, or 4 bytes. Whether those bits are stored with the most significant byte first or the least significant byte first depends on the hardware involved. More specifically, it depends on whether the hardware is [little endian or big endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Either way, the address of `x` in the example above will be the address of the first (lowest) byte in memory, so if you have:

```
char p[4] = (char*)&x;
```

then `p[0]` will be the first byte, `p[1]` the second byte, and so on. Endianness just tells you whether the first byte is the most significant or the least.

Answer (score 0):

Addresses refer to entire bytes, so it doesn't make sense to ask about the address of a bit. Most modern computers are little-endian (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499423/how-are-integers-stored-in-memory)), so you should get the address of the **least significant byte**.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by most guys, memory is byte-addressable and bits don't have individual addresses. Still if you want to access the bits(read/write into them), you can use the bit-shift operations with bitwise logical ones.